# Intentional use of "colossal" in The Andromeda Strain?

Tags: the-andromeda-strain

In the 'Situation Room' scene of 1971's *The Andromeda Strain*, Mr. Secretary is played by (in his final film role) Glenn Langan, who occupied the title role in the '50s sci-fi film, *[The Amazing Colossal Man](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Amazing_Colossal_Man)*.

At the end of the scene, Dr. Robertson expresses his disapproval of the president's decision to postpone Directive 712 for 24 to 48 hours, by saying,

> "It should have been left up to the scientists. **It's a colossal mistake**."

Given that Glenn Langan was the titular *Colossal Man*, was this choice of words an intentional reference?

Comment: Seems unlikely...it's a common hyperbolic expression

Answer (score 4):

According to *[The Making of Andromeda Strain](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ySSNU0d6fXY)* the screenplay was largely complete **before** primary casting took place.

The 1970 [cinescript](https://cinephiliabeyond.org/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/Andromeda-Strain-The-1970-05-28-Final-Draft.compressed.pdf) (available on the Andromeda Strain DVD) contains the line in question, written before any of the cast, including Langan, were signed on to the film which strongly indicates that this was *a happy coincidence* rather than *an intentional Easter-egg*.

[image]